# Refactoring tests vs implementation Rails and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, refactoring, tdd, capybara

What is the right way to refactor your tests so that there is no dependency on the implementation.  Right now if lets say the title or the text in the link was changed then the tests would also need to be fixed.  When you practice DRY (don't repeat yourself) this seems like a bad thing.  The solution I am looking for would only have my type "Some Random Title" once.

Should I move the result into a helper that the test and view have access to?

home.html.slim

```
doctype html
html
  head
title Some Random Title
  body
    = link_to "A Link", "#"
```

home_spec.rb

```
describe "Home Page" do
  subject { page }
  before { visit root_path }

  it { should have_title("Some Random Title") }
  it { should have_link("A Link") }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asserting on the string is (IMHO) the correct way to do this.

You want to ensure that when your view is rendered, the correct copy is rendered into the page. If you move this string into a helper, and reference it in both your spec and view then you're not really testing anything - except that the method got called. If (when) that helper stops returning the right value for title, this view test will not catch it.

However, if this view gets reused to render dynamic content you could extract the title copy to a helper, a decorator, or the i18n yaml files. Although I would *still* want to assert that the tile is "Some Random Title" in the test.

**Your tests don't have to be DRY**

[Don't make your tests DRY](http://www.testdrivenjs.com/2012/06/02/dont-make-your-tests-dry/)

Comment: awesome tx i was just about to say this. THEN I was going to say "If it hurts, do it more often." You want tests that are more brittle than production code. If they break one too many times, only then do you upgrade the test.